# задержка не работает как вложенная функция

Tags: javascript

Помогите начинающему!

Вопрос: Если записать код задержки алерта как:

```
setTimeout("T1()", 500);

function T1() {
  alert()
}
```

при загрузке алерт выскакивает.
Если оформить это действие как функцию FF() - программа не срабатывает.

В чем дело?

Весь скрипт таков.

```
<script>
function FF()
{
    setTimeout("T1()",500);
    function T1()
    {
        alert()
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <body bgcolor="00ff00">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: у тебя некорректная разметка: несколько элементов `body`, и функция `FF` нигде не вызывается, вот алерт и не появляется. И плюсом: при передаче строки - ее содержимое выполняется в глобальном контексте, а так как T1 - локальная функция по таймауту будет ошибка так как эта функция будет не найдена

Answer (score 1):

Чтоб функция отработала - её нужно вызвать, к примеру вот так:

```
<script>
function FF()
{
    setTimeout(T1,500);
    function T1()
    {
        alert()
    }
}
FF();
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <body bgcolor="00ff00">
</body>
</html>
```

Или же есть [самовызывающие](http://www.codehint.ru/articles/2014-07-27_javascript-self-invoking-functions) функции, у них нет названия, но они вызываются сразу же. Если брать за основу Ваш пример, это выглядело бы вот так:

```
(function () {
    setTimeout(T1,500);
    function T1()
    {
        alert()
    }
 }());
```

Comment: и если бы ты попробовал - то увидел бы, что это выдает ошибку: _ReferenceError: T1 is not defined_

Comment: @Grundy вместо того чтобы тыкать, можно было бы исправить просто, теперь всё работает верно

Comment: Вместо того, чтобы бросаться писать ответ, можно было проверить, что  советуешь

Comment: а пока проверяешь, можно вообще передумать отвечать :)

Comment: @Igor ответ ещё час назад поправил, он работает, можете проверять :)

Answer (score 1):

Просто оберните ваш алерт в функцию и все будет работать.

```js
function alertWithDelay() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    alert('alert-text')
  }, 5000);
}

alertWithDelay();
```

Comment: в вопросе alert уже обернут в функцию T1

Comment: @Grundy я вижу что написал автор, но разве имя функции пишется в кавычках?) с анонимной функцией не ошибется

Comment: _строка это допустимый параметр для setTimeout._

Comment: @Grundy, допустимый, то допустимый, но читабельность лично у меня теряется, имя функции это - имя функции и не требует кавычек, строка - это строка.